# Import Error when trying to import scrapy spider into django

Tags: python, django, import, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to run scrapy spiders from a django project when the user makes a request so I'm currently testing the code from the [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) for running a spider from a script. To test out how to import the spider into the django project, I added a file to the django project in the same directory where I placed the scrapy spider (i.e. where the urls, settings, and wsgi files are). When I try to import the function to run the crawler process from the spiders file, I get an import error. This is the statement I used:

```
from trydjango18.ticket_city_scraper.ticket_city_scraper.ticket_city_scraper.spiders.tc_spiders import spiderCrawl
```

This might seem vague so I have a screenshot of the file path below. What would be the proper way to import the spider.py file?

**filepath with scrapy spiders**
[image]

**filepath with test file**
[image]

**UPDATE**
I was able to get the the spider to run from the script; however, I now am getting another import error from within the spiders file for the items module. I think this is most likely due to the fact that only the path for the spiders.py is being added into the script but not the other necessary modules. These are the statements I used (as well as the rest of the code from the script):

```
import imp
tc_spider = imp.load_source('tc_spider', '/home/elijah/Desktop/trydjango18/src2/trydjango18/trydjango18/ticket_city_scraper/ticket_city_scraper/spiders/tc_spider.py')  


bandname = raw_input("Enter bandname")
tc_spider.spiderCrawl(bandname)
```

Comment: Note that using `imp.load_source('tc_spider', '/home/elijah/Desktop/trydjango18/src2/trydjango18/trydjango18/ticket_city_scraper/ticket_city_scraper/spiders/tc_spider.py')` makes your script environment-dependent.

Comment: @ErnestTen How will it become environment independent

Comment: You shouldn't use anything above your project's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see there are 2 errors:

1. There is extra `ticket_city_scraper` in your path.

   Should be:

   ```
   from trydjango18.ticket_city_scraper.ticket_city_scraper.spiders.tc_spiders import spiderCrawl
   ```
2. There is no `tc_spiders.py`.

   Either add `tc_spiders.py` or import from `tc_spider.py`.

Considering that you asked about

> the spider.py file

I assume that you meant `tc_spider.py`, thus a complete solution is:

```
from trydjango18.ticket_city_scraper.ticket_city_scraper.spiders.tc_spider import spiderCrawl
```

Also make sure that:

1. Each package contains `__init__.py`.
2. `tc_spiders.py`/`tc_spider.py` contains module-level function `spiderCrawl`.

Comment: I just made an update to the posts with the statements I got to work and the problem I'm having now. Do you if I there is a way that I can import all of the necessary modules like importing the whole scrapy folder? When I tried to add the path the items module like I did with the spider file, the error didn't go away. Thanks for the response btw

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 You can [import `*` from a package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), however, I would suggest you to explicitly import each module. Remember that "_Explicit is better than implicit._".